What do bloomberg mean by this carry measure?
https://assets.bbhub.io/professional/sites/10/Bloomberg-GSAM-Bond-Futures-Carry-Index-Fact-Sheet.pdf
On page two, they say

SELECTION & REBALANCE   On a monthly basis, the carry measure for each
of the eligible constituents (underlying government bond futures) is
calculated and the constituents are ranked in descending order in
terms of their carry measure. The index takes long  positions in the
top 1/3rd constituents with the highest carry and short positions in
the 1/3rd constituents with the  lowest.
SIGNAL DESCRIPTION  The carry measure reflects the expected return of
the bond futures, assuming yield curves do not change over the
following month. For all bond futures, except for the Australia bond
futures, the carry measure is defined to be the  yield of the relevant
Cheapest-to-Deliver (CTD) bond minus the relevant funding rate plus
the CTD bond's roll down return (estimated to be the product of its
modified duration and a linearly interpolated measure of the
localized slope of an appropriate section of the yield curve), divided
by 12. For Australia specifically, the yield and  modified duration of
the CTD bond is replaced by the average yield and average modified
duration of all  deliverable bonds.

I understand that somebody who buys a bond and funds it with a repo, earns the bond's carry, minus the funding rate. However, they are talking about bond futures... surely the bond futures holder doesn't earn any of this? You just get the bond at maturity for the futures price F - you certainly don't get any of the coupons and you're not paying the funding rate either? So what do they mean by this carry strategy?

Keep in mind that because of arbitrage, the price F of the future does take into account the funding rate, the dirty price of the CTD and the coupon if any that will be paid before  futures maturity. In the simplest case, while you are long the future an investment bank on the other side is short the future, is long the CTD financed by repo and will deliver it to you at maturity.

Correct - but there is no carry on a futures trade as far as I'm aware. Only rate risk.

In this futures strategy, you get carry+roll-financing on the CTD (so it is not just carry in the strict sense, the roll is also included). HTH.
